# Finding the average of scores

Tags: java, average

I am very new to java, whixh explains the loq quality code. I am trying to calculate the average of the scores i enter in my code, which is below, but it only gets the average of numbers i enter after the rest of the code has been executed. How do i get it to find the average of the scores that i put in earlier in the codeusing this line of code:
 System.out.printf(“%.2f”, average); 
To be clear I want the average of the numbers i enter after the line i have put asterisks on.
Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class week4
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

int n =1;

{
    do{
    n++;
    String studentname;

    int mark;

    Scanner inText = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the name of the student >> ");

    studentname = inText.nextLine();

    Scanner inNumber = new Scanner(System.in);

    *System.out.print("Please enter mark for student " + studentname + " out of 100 >> ");*


    mark = inText.nextInt();

    if(mark <50) System.out.println("The grade for " + studentname + " is F " );

    else if(mark <65) System.out.println("The grade for " + studentname + " is P " );

    else if(mark <75) System.out.println("The grade for " + studentname + " is C " );

    else if(mark <85) System.out.println("The grade for " + studentname + " is D " );

    else System.out.println("The grade for " + studentname + " is HD" );

    } while(n <=3);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                int sum = 0;
                int mark;
                int average;
                int counter = 1;

                while (counter < 2){
                    mark = input.nextInt();
                    sum = sum + mark;
                    counter++;
                    average = sum/3;
                    System.out.printf("The aerage score is " + average  );
                }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your average be some float?

Comment: Before we proceed: you want marks to be stored in `mark` variable, read them in the first `do-while` loop and then count the average, right?

Comment: That's a lot of `Scanner` on the System input.. You do the average on each loop using the same divider but you condition don't match, you will only read one value before stopping the loop

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It’s not very easy to read as it stands. Your IDE can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your this while code block at the end is unnecessary:

```
                    while (counter < 2){
                    mark = input.nextInt();
                    sum = sum + mark;
                    counter++;
                    average = sum/3;
                    System.out.printf("The average score is " + average  );
```

You should add a global variable like total. When user enter their marks, store each user score in total variable. Replace your code with this(Highlighted the change with bold):

```
public class week4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int total = 0;

        int n = 1;

        {
            do {
                n++;
                String studentname;

                int mark;

                Scanner inText = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.print("Please enter the name of the student >> ");

                studentname = inText.nextLine();

                Scanner inNumber = new Scanner(System.in);

                //*
                System.out.print("Please enter mark for student " + studentname + " out of 100 >> ");

                mark = inText.nextInt();
                **total += mark;**

                if (mark < 50) {
                    System.out.println("The grade for " + studentname + " is F ");
                } else if (mark < 65) {
                    System.out.println("The grade for " + studentname + " is P ");
                } else if (mark < 75) {
                    System.out.println("The grade for " + studentname + " is C ");
                } else if (mark < 85) {
                    System.out.println("The grade for " + studentname + " is D ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("The grade for " + studentname + " is HD");
                }

            } while (n <= 3);

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            int sum = 0;
            int mark;
            int average;
            int counter = 1;

            **average = total / 3;
            System.out.printf("The aerage score is " + average);**

        }
    }
```